# Invoke a class dynamically

Tags: c#, oop, .net-core

let's assume that I have two identical services from two providers and I want to write a code that calls either one of them depending on the client request.

To be more clear, I have provider A and provider B. A client will submit a request for either A or B, so I have to invoke their classes to handle the request.

I created the provider interface

```
interface IProviderInterface
{
    string GetRedirectUrl();
    string GetStatus();
}
```

then each provider class has implemented the interface

```
public class ProviderA: IProviderInterface
{
    public ProviderA()
    {
    }

    public string GetRedirectUrl()
    {
        return "URL for provider A";
    }

    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return "Check status with provider A API";
    }
}
```

Now in the provider manager class I used the switch statement to invoke the desired provider class.

```
public class ProvidersManager
{
    IProviderInterface ProviderObj;

    public ProvidersManager(string ProviderName)
    {
        switch (ProviderName)
        {
            case "A":
                ProviderObj = new ProviderA();
                break;
            case "B":
                ProviderObj = new ProviderB();
                break;
        }
    }

    public string GetRedirectUrl()
    {
        return  ProviderObj.GetRedirectUrl();
    }

    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return ProviderObj.GetStatus();
    }
}
```

But this method requires me to edit the provider manager class each time I add a new provider.

I was wondering if there was a way to invoke the desired class with a more dynamic way without altering the code.

Comment: reflection could do the job but its not recommended

Comment: Where are you getting the string ProviderName from? Why do you need . the provider manager instead of just passing around instances of IProviderInterface

Comment: You could inject the provider into the `ProviderManager` directly, or you could create a factory class that's responsible for creating providers.

Comment: You can have your providers register with ProvidersManager, which could then  maintain a dictionary, say, of registered providers by name. This is called the factory pattern, BTW (with or without the registration).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Haha, seems like we had the same idea. Feel free to critique my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DI` to avoid the changes in `ProvidersManager`.

Or you can just refactor this code and create a factory which can take the responsibility to provide the object of provide type for supplied provider name.

Answer (score 0):

There are some alternatives you could use to accomplish this:

## Generic type

```
public class ProvidersManager<TProvider> where TProvider : IProviderInterface
{
    public ProvidersManager() =>
       ProviderObj = Activator.CreateInstance<TProvider>();
}

// eg: new ProvidersManager<ProviderA>();
```

## Using type (loaded before somewhere else)

```
public ProvidersManager(Type providerImplementationType) =>
    ProviderObj = (IProviderInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

// eg: new ProvidersManager(typeof(ProviderA));
```

## Using type full name

```
public ProvidersManager(string providerFullName) =>
    ProviderObj = (IProviderInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.Load(providerFullName));

// eg: new ProvidersManager("MyApplication.Common.ProviderA");
```

Answer (score 0):

**ProviderManager.cs**

```
internal static class ProviderManager
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, BaseProvider> _providers = new Dictionary<string, BaseProvider>();

    public static void Register(string name, BaseProvider provider) => _providers.Add(name, provider);
    public static string GetRedirectUrl(string name) => _providers[name].GetRedirectUrl();
    public static string GetStatus(string name) => _providers[name].GetStatus();
}
```

**BaseProvider.cs**

```
internal abstract class BaseProvider
{
    private BaseProvider(string name) => ProviderManager.Register(name, this);  
    public abstract string GetRedirectUrl();
    public abstract string GetStatus();
}
```

**ProviderA.cs**

```
internal class ProviderA : BaseProvider
{
    private readonly string _redirectUrl;
    private readonly string _status;

    public ProviderA(string redirectUrl, string status) : base("A")
    {
        _redirectUrl = redirectUrl
        _status = status;
    }

    public string GetRedirectUrl() => _redirectUrl;
    public string GetStatus() => _status;
}
```

**Usage**

```
internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProviderA providerA = new ProviderA("http://stackoverflow.com", "active");
        string url = ProviderManager.GetRedirectUrl("A");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the manager constructor which takes `IProviderInterface` as a parameter.

```
public class ProvidersManager
{
    IProviderInterface ProviderObj;

    public ProvidersManager(IProviderInterface providerObj)
    {
        ProviderObj = providerObj;
    }

    public string GetRedirectUrl()
    {
        return  ProviderObj.GetRedirectUrl();
    }

    public string GetStatus()
    {
        return ProviderObj.GetStatus();
    }
}
```

Now, in the calling client pass the instance.

```
var providerManager = new ProvidersManager(new ProviderA());
var anotherProviderManager = new ProvidersManager(new ProviderB());
```

or go for [DI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1). Also, when using DI check [Service lifetimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<IProviderInterface, ProviderA>();
}
```

Comment: Having multiple managers doesn't even make sense it's a pointless layer of abstraction. The manager is supposed to abstract all the providers.

Comment: It is just for the understanding of passing different providers and it is not going to be the actual impl.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change code as you add new providers then you an use reflation

```
Type providerType = Type.GetType("Provider" + ProviderName);
ProviderObj = (IProviderInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(providerType);
```